# MYSQL Union a limit applied to second statement will not return records

Tags: mysql

Have got a little stuck on a query. I've simplified it down to it's essence.
1st statement is the select before the UNION ALL
2nd statement is the select after the UNION ALL.

Objective: to return all results in the 1st statement and then  limit the results of the 2nd statement.
What's happening: If I ask for the limit of 1 then it will not show me any records from the 2nd statement. But will show the 2 records of the 1st statement. 
Anyone know how to solve this?

```
CREATE
    OR REPLACE VIEW qrytest
     AS (
select *
from
(select field1,field2
from tableOne) as tbl1
UNION ALL
select *
from 
(select field1, field2
from tableOne limit 1) as tbl2

);


select *
from qrytest
where field2 = 10
```

Comment: Perhaps the where clause in the select from the view eliminates the record in question. But how do you think we can answer your question without knowing your data?

Answer (score 0):

Observe your `CREATE VIEW` statement; I don't think you need the second select statement as shown below since you are just duplicating a record in that table.

```
select *
from 
(select field1, field2
from tableOne limit 1) as tbl2
```

Your query can be modified to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW qrytest
     AS (
select field1,field2
from tableOne
);
```